# How to find and save all occurrences of pattern within a string

Tags: php, regex

```
 $testString = "76,2-2; 75,1-2.22; 79,2-3.6;";
```

How can I get the first value after - and before ; with a particular selection?

I tried multiple explodes but it does not seem good for performance.

For example for 76 expected value 2, for 75 expected value 2.22, for 79 expected value 3.6.

PS: Yes there are spaces before ID numbers.

Comment: In what format output should be ?

Comment: Just `explode` several times with appropriate characters.

Comment: Capture the first group from [\d+,\d+-(\d+(\.\d+)?);](https://regex101.com/r/iJ7uF8/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
$str = '76,2-2; 75,1-2.22; 79,2-3.6;'

preg_match_all('/(\d+),\d+-(\d+(?:\.\d+)?);/', $str, $m);

$output = array_combine ( $m[1], $m[2] );    
print_r($output);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [76] => 2
    [75] => 2.22
    [79] => 3.6
)
```

Resulting array has all key-value pairs that you're looking for. You can lookup any value like:

```
echo $output['76']
2

echo $output['75']
2.22

echo $output['79']
3.6
```

Answer (score 1):

anubhava's approach is great, especially if you want to process the string once and access the array multiple times, however this seems simpler:

```
 $find = 75; 
 preg_match("/$find,\d+-([^;]+)/", $testString, $match);

 echo $match[1];  // if found it will always be $match[1]
```